# Can a client get servlet's responses without a request?

Tags: java, servlets

In the traditional way for every client request I get servlet response.
something like this:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request)
```

Now I want to get updates from my servlet every time interval.
How can i catch the server's response?

For comparison when I worked with sockets the  code looked something like this:

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {            
        Object serverMessage = inStream.readObject();               
        // Do somthing with serverMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: What answer are you looking for beyond "put the `response = ` line inside the loop"?

Comment: Push, comet, websockets, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a server to client push with an approach called long polling, addressed here:
[Long Polling example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

HTTP is a request driven protocol. You could explore other messaging protocols depending on what you're doing. Anything from Web Sockets to basic TCP, to a variety of frameworks that build ostensibly richer apis on top of tcp. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

No. The client will have to make more requests to which the server -> servlet then responds.

You can however (by e.g. Javascript) try to make the client send a request at a regular interval.